# Favorite Question and Answers from Third Quarter 2020

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

The question is now closed and the [blog post](https://thesffblog.com/2020/10/highlights-from-2020-3rd-quarter/) has been created.

### Original

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from July 1st 2019 through September 30th 2020.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2020/01/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2020/01/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2020/01/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this half year. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/550327/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/618952/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Additionally if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

### **Pandemic Suggestions?**

Have you watched, read, or experienced anything amazing over this time as result of quarantine? You may also mention that. For instance, you watched something you hadn't seen before, and that exceeded your expectations. Mention it!

Answer (score 4):

I quite liked a few this quarter.

This one because the complexity of the world created by Lucas means there isn't just one singular answer but *several*.

- [Why did Mace Windu and the Jedi Council refuse to raise Anakin to the rank of Master?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226416/why-did-mace-windu-and-the-jedi-council-refuse-to-raise-anakin-to-the-rank-of-ma)

This one because it was *surprisingly difficult* to find a canon answer.

- [In Star Trek, are food replicators also used by everyday people as a household item?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225993/in-star-trek-are-food-replicators-also-used-by-everyday-people-as-a-household-i)

And this one because @Skooba managed to find me an authorised answer 6 years after I asked it.

- [Was Lucius Malfoy actually going to kill Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72236/was-lucius-malfoy-actually-going-to-kill-harry-potter)

Answer (score 0):

*Big Hero 6: The Series* was a fun series to watch, at least for the first two seasons. I thought I wouldn't really enjoy it because I didn't remember much of the movie, but it definitely served as a good branching point off of the movie.

It's available on Disney+ and Disney XD On-Demand, if you want to watch it.

Comment: The point is this question is to showcase good *questions asked in the past three months*, not good *shows you have watched in the past three months*. There is a significant difference between the two.

Comment: @matt - I don't think we need to worry too much about how closely we match the question when it comes to the quarterly blog post. We can also use it for announcements, musings, etc etc